# Nodejs: why should one close down the process when an error occurs?

Tags: node.js

Nodejs's default behavior is to shut down when an error makes it to the main event loop.  The manual strongly recommends not overriding this behavior (for instance, via `process.on('uncaughtException`).

The explanation given is:

> An unhandled exception means your application - and by extension
>   node.js itself - is in an undefined state. Blindly resuming means
>   anything could happen.
>
> Think of resuming as pulling the power cord when you are upgrading
>   your system. Nine out of ten times nothing happens - but the 10th
>   time, your system is bust.

Can someone elaborate on this?  Chrome, which uses the same V8 engine as node, resumes its event loop after an uncaught error by default, and AFAIK this doesn't cause any problems.  So it doesn't seem like there's any intrinsic reason that V8 can't recover gracefully from an uncaught exception.  Is there something in the node internals that behaves differently than Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer does not have anything to do with the engine's ability to restart itself.

It has to do with your own application code. If an unhandled exception occurs, then there is inherently no way of understanding your application's state. If there were, then it would not have been an *unhandled* exception.  And, if you do not know your state, then you cannot be sure that more unhandled exceptions will not continue to occur, most likely causing worse-and-worse issues as time progresses (as unexpected states cascade into more-and-more unexpected states).

Imagine this as code that is running on the server (as it is not at all specific to node.js):

```
start process
open two server sockets
process incoming requests
```

If you were to fail to open the second server socket without handling the exception, then chances are your application will not work. Restarting the thread at the next logical step would likely fail to work properly as well.  Restarting the engine could not reasonably close the one socket, and it would be unlikely to fix the cause of the second failure (most likely the port is already in use), and if it did close the successfully opened socket, then it had better restart the application so that it can be reopened (or else it made it worse).

That is perhaps an obvious case, but now imagine that you are a graphics application (e.g., a game):

```
start process
load models
handle state (until closing)
   draw screen
```

If any model failed to load without exception handling, then the process cannot reasonably continue because it will simply cause more errors while drawing.

There are cases where recovering from unhandled exceptions is reasonable. In most client side GUI frameworks there is a way to register for unhandled exceptions, which allows the restarting of the event thread (GUI thread), analogous to Chrome's V8 recovery.  It is dangerous because recovery is not guaranteed; whatever caused the unhandled exception could still be in memory and ready to cause the exception *again* on the next usage of it.  However, it's also possible that a well developed application can be *small enough* to wipe itself clean given such exceptions.  The *best* use of such handlers (handling of unhandled exceptions) is to log the exception so that the issue can be fixed.

To put it differently: imagine an exception occurs that you did not handle in your application *anywhere*. What can you do to fix it so that it does not happen on the very next pass of the code? To safely answer that implies that you know what caused it, which means that A) it should not be unhandled and B) it is isolated.

The only guaranteed safe reset is to start from the very beginning, which means to restart the application.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the detailed answer.  This approach still feels strange to me, though.  Suppose you have a node application that's acting as a server, and every 100th request causes some unanticipated error.  Rather than restarting the server on those errors (interfering with all the other requests), wouldn't it be better to design it so there's no shared state between requests, letting you safely terminate the offending request while leaving the system as a whole running?

Comment: You are inherently sharing the socket/server state though, so you must catch and therefore handle any exception above that level (within your request).  If you have a stateless request handler, which is the ideal case, and you catch _all_ exceptions there, then you can safely say that you handled the exception and avoid restarting anything; you can also safely respond to that request with a somewhat meaningful error.  However, doing that avoids the situation bubbling into an _unhandled_ exception because you handled it.

Comment: Had you let the exception bubble to node.js, then the runtime has no way of knowing whether the exception was a fluke from input to a stateless request versus some stateful request that is going to blow up for every subsequent request.  This therefore forces the burden onto you to handle your exceptions, which is the only way for any runtime to safely consider it handled because the layer above (the runtime) has no way of knowing what is appropriate handling versus not because they cannot understand your code (if a runtime allowed you to flag your service's state-ness would help to do this).